# Object Does Not Name a Type

Tags: c++, sdl

I have looked at the SDL documentation, and an online tutorial regarding its use, but I must be doing something incorrectly.

```
SDL_Rect TOP_LEFT_VIEWPORT;
TOP_LEFT_VIEWPORT.x = 0;
TOP_LEFT_VIEWPORT.y = 0;
TOP_LEFT_VIEWPORT.h = HEIGHT / 2;
TOP_LEFT_VIEWPORT.w = WIDTH / 2;
```

The line after I declare `TOP_LEFT_VIEWPORT` the compiler says "TOP_LEFT_VIEWPORT does not name a type"
I also attempted copy-pasting the code example from https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Rect and it also received the same error.
Thanks for any responses!

Comment: My guess: `SDL_Rect` is declared **but** not defined.

Comment: My guess: You need to include sth.

Comment: @MohitJain SDL_Rect is just a structure though.  Is there really any more I could do other than declare it, then define all four of its attributes? It shouldn't make a difference if I define it on the same line I declare it in this scenario I think.

Comment: You have written this at "file scope", outside of any function.

Comment: You should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)